# Icons missing/incorrect after installing and using xRDP on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

Tags: server, unity, icons, mate

I just successfully installed xRDP with the MATE Core install on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. I was able to successfully connect to the server remotely. However, after the install, when I am viewing the server via a console through VMWARE some of the icons are missing or are incorrect and the terminal now looks different. I believe this had something to do with the installing MATE but I am not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas how to get the default UNITY desktop back? Also knowing how/why this occurred and how to fix it would be useful if this happens in the future.

****EDIT****
I installed the Unity Tweak Tool and selected all of the defaults for Unity in the Tweak Tool and all of the icons and display returned to normal.

[image: Attached is a picture of the icons and my terminal.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the Unity Tweak Tool and selected all of the defaults for Unity in the Tweak Tool and all of the icons and display returned to normal.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

From there, select all of the default Unity icons, cursors, docks etc. Then reboot your workstation if you would like.